# Finish cracks between sides and back?

Tags: string-instruments, repair, mandolin

I recently bought a seven year old used mandolin online. It has edge binding where the sides meet the top but not the back. Where the sides meet the back, the finish has little cracks along that seam, almost the entire way around the instrument. There are links to pictures below.

Is this normal? Expected? It *seems* unexpected to me but maybe I've never looked that closely at an acoustic instrument that didn't have binding along both edges.

[image: Cracks near tailpiece]

[image: Cracks near point]

Comment: I’m not an expert. From what I know, seems like humidity might not have been controlled enough and the back and sides swelled or shrank differently and cracked the finish from the inside. But that’s just a guess

Answer (score 2):

First: don't just rely on strangers with photos; take it to an expert! They could spot all kinds of stuff and tell you what to do about it if anything.

But I'll say that it looks to me more like "scuffs" or "gouges" than cracks. They certainly don't look to me like cracks that go all the way through the wood; that would be a big deal, but "crazing" in a finish is just aesthetic, and any gouges might detract from value and appeal but shouldn't matter to the sound. From the first picture I was going to guess it was caused by a shoulder strap, but you say it's all the way around.

But again, take it in to somebody who knows what they're doing! No matter what you see, a "checkup" is in order when getting a new instrument.

Comment: I agree that it needs to be seen in person by a luthier.  To me it looks like cracks occurring at the glue joint between sides and back, as if the back were squeezed inward and those joints stressed.